# SQL Server : creating a view from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have 2 tables, one with hoppers and the ingredients in them (Recorded once a day or when ingredients are changed)

Example:

```
Hoppers |  Ingredients  |   Timestamp
--------+---------------+----------------------
Hop_1   |  Ing_A        |   8/22/2016 06:00:00
Hop_2   |  Ing_B        |   8/22/2016 06:00:00
```

etc...

And I have a second table that has totals used from each hopper recorded every hour

Example:

```
Name               |   Value  |   Timestamp
-------------------+----------+---------------------
Hop_1 Daily Total  |  100     |   8/22/2016 11:00:00
Hop_1 Run Total    |   30     |   8/22/2016 11:00:00
```

etc...

I would like to create a view that shows amount produced from each hopper and says the name.

Example:

```
Hop_1 Ingredient | Hop_1 Daily | Hop_1 Run | Timestamp  
-----------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------
Ing_A            |      100    |      30   | 8/22/2016 11:00:00
```

Sorry if it doesn't look good, I'm new at formatting

Comment: so there is no column to join the 2 tables by, other than cutting up the first part of the Name column?  How would you identify which Value goes with which ingredient if there are more than 1 ingredients?  And if you want a pivot with column names specific to hopper what will you do when more than 1 hopper is present?  Add additional columns?

Comment: Yes the final table would be all hoppers, and all daily totals, ect.. i just didn't want to type it all out... I was hoping i could group them somehow by the timestamp from each table... however the timestamps won't equal eachother, My idea is to load the values for daily total, and run total, then using that timestamp then  look for the most recent timestamp in the other table. I'm just not sure how to accomplish this. The reason I'm trying to do it this way is because I'm just trying to organize information in an previously created database

Comment: I am sorry Neal your comment doesn't address my questions, perhaps I didn't specify them well.  1) how do you relate between the tables? so how do you know Ing_A goes to the Value if there is more than 1 ingredient? 2) how will the hoppers be represented in the final table, additional columns for every hopper?  You are not getting too much attention on the site probably because your question doesn't answer some of the unknowns and also because you are not showing an attempt to get what you want even if that attempt is way off

Comment: 1. Relation between tables, When ingredients are changed in a hopper the run total is reset to 0. (and the new ingredient is entered into the database with a timestamp) So I should know based off the timestamp. if at 11:30AM Run total is 500 I can look at ingredeint where Ingredients.Timestamp < Totals.Timestamp and look at the newest entry for that query. This would tell me how much i've used. (if this isn't clear enough let me konw)

Comment: 2. In the final table their will be columns for Hopper1 Ingredient, Hopper1 Run Total, Hopper1 Daily Total, Hopper2 Ingredient, Hopper2 Run Total, Hopper2 Daily Total.

Answer (score 0):

For the record I don't really think that structure is the best idea because it requires dynamic sql to pull it off with a couple of loops and lots of LEFT SELF JOINS.  But here you go:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Ingredients') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Ingredients
    END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Totals') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Totals
    END

CREATE TABLE #Ingredients (Hoppers VARCHAR(25), Ingredeients VARCHAR(25), [Timestamp] DATETIME)
CREATE TABLE #Totals (Name VARCHAR(50), Value INT, [Timestamp] DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Ingredients (Hoppers, Ingredeients, [Timestamp])
VALUES ('Hop_1','Ing_A','8/22/2016 06:00:00'),('Hop_2','Ing_B','8/22/2016 06:00:00'),('Hop_3','Ing_C','8/22/2016 06:00:00')
INSERT INTO #Totals (Name, Value, [Timestamp])
VALUES ('Hop_1 Daily Total',100,'8/22/2016 11:00:00'),('Hop_1 Run Total',30,'8/22/2016 11:00:00'),('Hop_1 Run Total',60,'8/22/2016 09:00:00')
,('Hop_2 Daily Total',500,'8/22/2016 11:00:00'),('Hop_2 Run Total',10,'8/22/2016 11:00:00'),('Hop_2 Run Total',5,'8/22/2016 10:00:00')
,('Hop_3 Daily Total',400,'8/22/2016 11:00:00'),('Hop_3 Run Total',85,'8/22/2016 11:00:00'),('Hop_3 Run Total',65,'8/22/2016 10:00:00')


DECLARE @HopperCount INT
SELECT @HopperCount = COUNT(DISTINCT i.Hoppers)
FROM
    #Ingredients i
    INNER JOIN #Totals t
    ON t.Name LIKE i.Hoppers + '%'


DECLARE @I INT = 1
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = '
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       i.Hoppers
       ,i.Ingredeients
       ,Value
       ,t.[Timestamp]
       ,CASE WHEN t.Name LIKE ''%Daily%'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsDaily
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.Hoppers, t.name ORDER BY t.[Timestamp] DESC) as RunRowNum
       ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY i.Hoppers) as HooperNumber
    FROM
       #Ingredients i
       INNER JOIN #Totals t
       ON t.Name LIKE i.Hoppers + ''%''
       AND i.[Timestamp] <= t.[Timestamp]
)

SELECT
    c.Ingredeients AS [Hop_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Ingredient]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.IsDaily = 1 THEN c.Value END) AS [Hop_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Daily]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.IsDaily = 0 THEN c.Value END) AS [Hop_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Run]
    ,MAX(c.[Timestamp]) AS [Hop_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Timestamp] '


SET @I = 2
WHILE @I <= ISNULL(@HopperCount,0)
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = @Sql + '
    ,c'+ CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) +  '.Ingredeients AS [Hop_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Ingredient]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN c'+ CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.IsDaily = 1 THEN c' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.Value END) AS [Hop_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Daily]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN c' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.IsDaily = 0 THEN c' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10))+ '.Value END) AS [Hop_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Run]
    ,MAX(c' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.[Timestamp]) AS [Hop_' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Timestamp] '

    SET @I = @I + 1
END


SET @Sql = @Sql + '
FROM
    cte c '


SET @I = 2
WHILE @I <= ISNULL(@HopperCount,0)
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = @Sql + '
    LEFT JOIN cte c' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' 
    ON c.HooperNumber + ' + CAST(@I - 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' = c' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.HooperNumber 
    AND c' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10))+ '.RunRowNum = 1
    AND c.IsDaily = c' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.IsDaily '

    SET @I = @I + 1
END

SET @Sql = @Sql + '
WHERE
    c.HooperNumber = 1
    AND c.RunRowNum = 1
GROUP BY
    c.Ingredeients
'

SET @I = 2
WHILE @I <= ISNULL(@HopperCount,0)
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ',c' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.Ingredeients
    '

    SET @I = @I + 1
END

EXECUTE (@sql)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Pivot table for your need.
Here's a link : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx